# What is the default Audacious bit depth for PulseAudio output?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, music

I wonder what is normal Bit Depth for Audacious Player there are 16/24/32 bits available I tried them all seems fine.

I use stereo output for my speakers and I wonder what bit depth be the best for stereo output so not to overload the hardware or some, right now I set it to 24 bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't hear any difference when your music is still mastered with [CD quality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_Disc_Digital_Audio) (PCM with 44,1 kHz samplerate and 16 bit audio bit depth) for mainstream consumption ([loudness war](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loudness_war)).

Changing the PulseAudio defaults - which are set to CD quality - and setting higher values while still playing the same material from mainstream equipment will only result in computational overhead.

Questions on audio quality are often confused with questions on music taste or general preference.

---

Going beyond mainstream audio equipment and music formats (lossless CD rips are still mainstream) is rather off-topic for this site, but Monty Montgomery's lengthy article on *[Why 24-bit/192kHz music downloads make no sense](http://people.xiph.org/~xiphmont/demo/neil-young.html)* is worth a read.

Comment: This is absolutely true

Answer (score 1):

Pulseaudio: 
/etc/pulse/client.conf:

```
; default-sample-format = s16le   # = PCM 16 bits
; default-sample-rate = 44100
; default-sample-channels = 2
; default-channel-map = front-left,front-right
```

These are the default values that pulseaudio uses for the downmix. If you play other bitrates, they will be converted to 44.1 kHz and sampleformat will always be truncated to 16 bits.
So it is a bit useless to go for 24-bit unless you uncomment and change these values but you will absolutely need Hi-end studio gear to notice some differences though. (and only if, of course, your source material is 24 bit too)

If your audiocard can only do 48 kHz you best change the downmixrate to 48 kHz because the samplerateconverter in pulseaudio is quite a bit better that the samplerateconverter in ALSA(=the driver for your audiocard). You can even change the conversion algorythm. See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/pulse-daemon.conf.5.html

Comment: You are pasting commented (not active) options from a configuration file without explanation. This does not provide an answer to the question.

Comment: It is common practise amongst programmers to set unactive options on default values as an informative template. Don't think that just because it is commented that it is automatically meaningless. These values happen to be the default values of pulse-audio. The options are self-explanatory but I will edit my answer to add some useful extra info.

Comment: That's much better now.

Answer (score 0):

The more refined speaker systems make use of the higher sample rates and can discern greater bitrates.  For a laptop there isn't that much worry with default speakers, but plug it in to a set of harman kardon speakers and you would hear the difference.  This comes from setting up systems that can be heard at a concert as clearly sitting in the loges as standing in front of the stage, speaker matching, balancing volume and tone.

Sorry I digressed: Default seems to be 44100, 16 bit; I set it to 44100 32 bit. I get nothing from PCM,it's just dead space. Same in Ubuntu as for Windows on my laptop. Was set at that rate in the beginning.

Comment: That's just a verbatim copy of marketing bogus without any scientific foundation. The OP didn't even ask about sample rates. http://www.xiph.org/video/vid1.shtml

Comment: Regardless, I am answering to both increased sampling and higher bitrates. OP also didn't mention the speakers he is using. Count me three strikes, i'm out.

Comment: Hmmm...This doesn't make much sense. 16/32 bit has nothing to do with samplerate. Speakers are analog and do nothing with samples and the conclusion isn't right. You don't win anything using 32 bit...(96 dB S/N-ratio is already much more than needed) only a higher samplerate could give you some benefits. Although the biggest damage to sound is samplerate conversion so best to keep the rate and format of the source you are playing.